# How do I order display of html and php content

Tags: php, html

I am retrieving posts from my database but I want the `<div class="welcome-text"><strong>This is my second output</strong> </div>`  to display below the retrieved table but its always displaying above. is there any way I can fix this:

```
<?php
while($posts_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts_result))
{
    echo '
    <tr class="topic-post">
            <td class="user-post">' . $posts_row['user_name'] . '<br/>' . date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($posts_row['post_date'])) . '</td>
            <td class="post-content">' . htmlentities(stripslashes($posts_row['post_content'])) . '</td>
          </tr>

          ';
}
?>
<div class="welcome-text"><strong>This is my second output</strong> </div>
```

[image]

Would use mysqli or prepared statement soon as I get this fixed

Comment: Can you show the full html, I guess you don't close the table before the `welcome-text`

Comment: Thats true I did not close the table at the appropriate position. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Validating your HTML output helps spot such errors. https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You din't close table tag before open div tag.

```
<table> 
<?php
    while($posts_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts_result))
    {
        echo '
        <tr class="topic-post">
                <td class="user-post">' . $posts_row['user_name'] . '<br/>' . date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($posts_row['post_date'])) . '</td>
                <td class="post-content">' . htmlentities(stripslashes($posts_row['post_content'])) . '</td>
              </tr>

              ';
    }
    ?>
</table>
    <div class="welcome-text"><strong>This is my second output</strong> </div>
```

Comment: Its working fine now, I should have closed table before the div